# Оператор FULL JOIN выдает ошибку "#1054 - Unknown column..."

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Есть две таблицы.

cats

[image: cats]

shops

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод который необходимо получить при помощи FULL JOIN:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке сделать такой запрос

```
SELECT cats.name, shops.shopname FROM cats FULL JOIN shops ON cats.shop_id = shops.id;
```

получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает FULL JOIN, насколько мне известно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL отсутствует FULL JOIN. Его нужно "собирать":

```
SELECT cats.name, shops.shopname 
FROM cats 
LEFT JOIN shops ON cats.shop_id = shops.id

UNION ALL

SELECT cats.name, shops.shopname 
FROM cats 
RIGHT JOIN shops ON cats.shop_id = shops.id
WHERE cats.shop_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Ясно! Благодарю.